# How to add amount of hours determined from a column to a timestamp column?

Tags: sql, presto

I have two columns, created_time(timestamp) and total_hours(float):

```
created_time
2020-11-22 20:01:02.000
2020-11-30 03:52:16.000
2020-11-19 00:22:16.000
```

```
total_hours
66
22.97
0.18
```

I'd like to be able to add total_hours onto created_time to return another column representing completed_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add hours to a timestamp:

```
select created_time + total_hours * interval '1' hour
```

Comment: select created_time + total_hours * interval '1' hour